# Ad-Hoc network has no IP under ipconfig

Tags: windows, networking

I created an adhoc network on Windows XP with these parameters :
IP 192.168.0.1, mask 255.255.255.0, no DNS

But under ipconfig I have nothing that shows up, it says that the network card is not connected. In the network list though, it says I'm connected to the network in the sum-up you have when doing a signle left click on the network, but says I'm not connected right above the bars that indicate the 'percentage of connection'.

I did disable the firewall, but I'm a newbie to this so it might come from anywhere.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ipconfig /renew` to renew the connection to all network cards.

Comment: It outputed me the following error (which I translate) :

Comment: Operation failed because no card has the authorized status for this operation (sorry, double post)